# New Identity Claims Disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 application in which I use Azure authentication. Once the user is authenticated, I want to add a new claim based on data I retrieved from the database.

I am using the following code to do this:

```
var userID = await GetId(User.Identity?.Name.ToString());

if (userID != 0)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("MyClaim", userID.ToString())
            };

    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

    User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

This seems to work:

[image]

You can see both the `ClaimsIdentity` from the Azure and the one I created to store the claim. I can drill down and see the value:

[image]

However, as soon as I'm redirected to the next page, the `ClaimIdentity` is not longer accessible:

[image]

What am I missing for the claims to persist and how would I retrieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume that claims are read from some kind of token and adding claims locally for current request will not change the token, but TBH I have not worked with Azure Auth.

Comment: did you have deal with "HttpContext!.SignInAsync" before? , if yes, It cannot be done again to make a claim...if not, you have wrong approach about your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public MyClaimsTransformation(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var claimType = "IdContact";

        if (principal.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            int idContact;

            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                idContact = await _context.Contacts
                    .Where(u => u.Email == principal.Identity.Name)
                    .Select(u => u.IdContact)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            }

            if (idContact != 0)
            {
                if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == claimType))
                {
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, idContact.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }

        principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        return await Task.FromResult(principal).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Using IClaimsTransformation to make the claim persist and using IServiceScopeFactory to access DbContext to pull info for the claim from the database.

Also, need to add the following line in program.cs:

```
  Builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformation>();
```

Comment: JFYI `await Task.FromResult(principal).ConfigureAwait(false)` - this `await` is completely pointless. Just `return principal` should suffice.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, that's why the .ConfigureAwait(false). But if I don't put it, I can't do public async Task and changing that 'caused other issues. So I keep it. But I will revisit that.